# Prove that $\sqrt{8}$ is irrational in different method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I tried to prove that $\sqrt{8}$ is irrational. I said let $\sqrt{8}$ be rational then $\sqrt{8}$ = $a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Then $2\sqrt{2}=a/b$ , and $\sqrt{2} =a/(2b)$. it is obvious that $RHS$ is rational and $LHS$ is irrational (assumed that $\sqrt{2}$ is proved). So there is a contradiction and proof done.

My question is that is there other ways to prove that $\sqrt{8}$ is irrational?

Comment: Actually, using that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrationnal to prove that $\sqrt{8}$ is irrationnal is quite weird, since these two facts can be proved the exact same way.

Comment: And $\sqrt{8} = \sqrt{4}\cdot \sqrt{2} = 2\cdot \sqrt{2}$

Comment: I don't think it's weird at all to use irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ to prove that $\sqrt 8$ is irrational. Using earlier results to simplify proofs of later results happens all the time in maths (though usually on a somewhat bigger scale, but still). This proof could be streamlined a little more by using the fact that the product of two rationals is rational, which is very easily proved, and then saying "suppose $\sqrt 8$ is rational. Then $\tfrac 12 \cdot \sqrt 8 = \sqrt 2$ is also rational", and using that as your contradiction, without needing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: To enlarge the scale somewhat, once you have proved that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, you can then use it to write a pretty much identical proof that $\frac{c}{d}\sqrt{2}$ is irrational for every $c,d \in \mathbb Z - \{0\}$.

Comment: if $n$ is not a perfect square then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational. you can use that for any number that is not $4,9,16,25,36,\cdots, n^2$

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Of course, it is logically ok to use the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ to prove the one of $\sqrt{8}$, I am not saying that it is incorrect. But in my opinion, someone who looks for a proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{8}$ should not use the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ : indeed these two facts are immediately equivalent, the "difficult" part is hidden in the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. It is like proving a property $A$, assuming that some trivially equivalent property $B$ is satisfied... Moreover, a direct proof for $\sqrt{8}$ is not longer than the one for $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $\sqrt{8}$ is equal to $\frac {a}{b}$ where $(a,b)=1$

Then $8 = \frac {(a^2)}{(b^2)}$ , so $8(b^2)= a^2$

Because of the fact that $(a,b)$ are relatively prime $b$ cannot divide $a$.Hence $8|a^2$.

Then ,let's say $a=2k$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

Then $8(b^2)=(2k)^2$. Then,by simplification $2(b^2)=k^2$ .It is obvious that  $k$ is an even integer, so k=2m where m is positive integer.

so $2(b^2)=(k^2)=(2m)^2$.then $b=8m b^2 = 2(m^2)$.As a result $2|b$ .

we concluded that a and b have common divisor which is $2$. it is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the equation $x^2-8=0$ and apply the Rational Root Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to write $\sqrt{8}$ as a continued fraction and then apply Lagrange´s theorem to conclude that it is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact (that works for any non perfect square (i'e. is a square of a whole number) ) that :

If $$\sqrt{n} =a/b$$ then $$a^2
n=b^2$$

Then **because the exponents of prime decomposition are all even at the right side of the expression and somes are odd at the left (because $n$ isn't a perfect square)**

$\sqrt{n} $ cannot be rational as $n$ isn't a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

Another Proof.

Let if possible $\sqrt 8$ be a rational number. Then it can be written in $\dfrac{p}{q}$ form where, $p,q$ are integers and $q\neq0$ and $(p,q)=1$, so that $\sqrt 8=\dfrac{p}{q}$. But we know, $\sqrt4=2<\sqrt8<3=\sqrt9$.
$\therefore 2<\dfrac{p}{q}<3 \implies 2q<p<3q$  or  $0<p-2q<q.$ 
Thus $p-2q$ is an integer that is less than $q$, so that $\sqrt8(p-2q)$ or $\dfrac{p}{q}(p-2q)$ is not an integer.
But $\sqrt8(p-2q)=\dfrac{p}{q}(p-2q) = \dfrac{p^2}{q}-2p  =\dfrac{p^2}{q^2}\cdot q-2p=8q-2p$. (which is an integer). 
$\implies \sqrt8(p-2q)$ is an interger.
Here we arrived at a contradiction.
Hence, $\sqrt8$ is not a rational number.
(Proved).

Comment: I see no flaw. +1